# Scala Iterator/Stream with Known Size

Tags: scala, stream, iterator

I have a Scala `Iterator` (I can use either datatype comfortably for my purpose) which I've cast from a `Seq`. I'd like to keep it around until I'm ready for it, but I'd also like to be able to get the size of it in O(1). I was wondering if there is a built-in way of setting things up that would allow me to keep hold of the iterator size on the iterable object.

Comment: Why do you need to pass the iterator around instead of the original `Seq`? By the way you wrote *cast*... You cannot cast from `Seq` to `Iterator` so I assume you mean `seq.iterator`. It seems to me that manipulating the iterator but needing to know the size is risky. As soon as a method that has access to the iterator calls `next()` that will change the size of the iterator...

Comment: I could see it being useful if you're producing a crapload of data and intend to throw it into an `Array`. The usual `Iterator`->`Array` pathway must use growable arrays, which is fine asymptotically but can generate a decent amount of garbage if you have lots of data, and is unfortunate if you know the size beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to wrap it in another iterator, if you can pay the cost of an extra indirection.

```
class SizedIterator[A](underlying: Iterator[A], val initalSize: Int) extends Iterator[A] {
  def next = underlying.next
  def hasNext = underlying.hasNext
}
```

and then

```
new SizedIterator(mySeq.iterator, mySeq.length)
```

Keep in mind, however, that if you map or whatever your new `SizedIterator` you will end up with a plain `Iterator` and no longer know how long the `initialSize` was.

Also keep in mind that you won't know how much of the iterator is consumed, so `initialSize` is an upper bound on the size, but when you use it there might be none left.

Alternatively, you can

```
mySeq.iterator.zipWithIndex.map{ case (x,i) => (x, mySeq.length-1) }.take(mySeq.length)
```

to produce an `Iterator` that is pairs of the element and the number of elements left (including that one--you'll never hit zero this way).

If you just want something with a known size that will tell you in `O(1)`, the `.length` method on an `Seq` cast to `Iterable` will resolve as fast as the method would have when it was a `Seq`--this is the whole point of overriding methods--and therefore won't (usually) consume a new `Iterator` each time.  But this requires you to keep the `Iterable` around, not just an `Iterator`.

Comment: @alex23 - Anything you do to an iterator may consume it all (except `hasNext`, and `next` will consume only one element).  You can find the size, but then there's nothing left (in general--it doesn't even promise that, but it doesn't promise _not_ to consume it , and that's the simplest way to implement size).  Your only hope is to call methods that themselves return an iterator that is what you want (which may just be the same iterator with updated state, but that's up to the implementation to decide), until your very last call (which produce anything, as long as you end with what you want).

Comment: I'm not convinced that your `SizedIterator` adds anything much over a plain pair `(Iterator[T], Int)` ... can you persuade me otherwise?

Comment: @MilesSabin - It does not offer much.  It keeps the `Iterator[T]` interface so you can pass it anywhere an `Iterator[T]` is needed and pattern match it back out again to recover the length, but this is not generally advisable when trying to write robust code.  I offered it as the closest solution to what is asked for.  I'm not sure that it wouldn't have been better to ask for something else!

Comment: @RexKerr what is your suggested solution for `Stream`? It cannot be extended like `Iterator`

Comment: @MinhThai - Just pass around a `(Stream, Int)` pair.